# Optimize Perl script - runs too slow on 40GB+ files

Tags: perl, date, optimization, data-conversion

I made the following Perl script to handle some file manipulation at work, but it's running far too slowly at the minute to be put in production.

I don't know Perl very well (not one of my languages), so can someone help me identify and replace parts of this script that would be slow given it's processing ~40 million lines?

Data being piped in is in the format:

```
col1|^|col2|^|col3|!|
col1|^|col2|^|col3|!|
... 40 million of these.
```

The date_cols array is calculated before this part of the script and basically holds the index of columns containing dates in the pre-converted format.

Here's the part of the script that will be executed for every input row.  I've cleaned it up a little and added comments, but let me know if anything else is needed:

```
## Read from STDIN until no more lines are arailable.
while (<STDIN>)
{       
    ## Split by field delimiter
    my @fields = split('\|\^\|', $_, -1);   

    ## Remove the terminating delimiter from the final field so it doesn't
    ## interfere with date processing.
    $fields[-1] = (split('\|!\|', $fields[-1], -1))[0];

    ## Cycle through all column numbres in date_cols and convert date
    ##  to yyyymmdd
    foreach $col (@date_cols)
    {
        if ($fields[$col] ne "")
        {
            $fields[$col] = formatTime($fields[$col]);
        }
    }

    print(join('This is an unprintable ASCII control code', @fields), "\n");
}           

## Format the input time to yyyymmdd from 'Dec 26 2012 12:00AM' like format.
sub formatTime($)
{
    my $col = shift;        

    if (substr($col, 4, 1) eq " ") {
        substr($col, 4, 1) = "0";
    }       
    return substr($col, 7, 4).$months{substr($col, 0, 3)}.substr($col, 4, 2);
}
```

Comment: have you thought about splitting the file into pieces first using something like `csplit`?

Comment: How does that work, and would it be able to reassemble them after assuming I ran this script on all the pieces?

Comment: I don't see any obvious inefficiencies.  The `print` function will be by far the slowest of what is shown, but I assume that is just for debugging purposes.  If you run exactly this code (minus the `print`) is it still slow?  *I am a bit suspicious, because the `trim` sub is not used anywhere.*

Comment: If you can split the file you might be able to throw more hardware at it - run it on 4 machines with only 10M records each.  It all depends on how easy it is to split & reassemble

Comment: @dan1111 split was used before, but I decided to remove it from the loop because I don't think it's required and I was trying to speed it up.  Forgot to remove the sub, my bad.  The print function... I do use it, that's how I pipe the output to a file that holds the conversion.  Is that a problem?  It's not displayed on screen.

Comment: Oh, and the char in the join is \022, but it doesn't display so I just put text there to state what it is.

Comment: Instead of the second `split`, you could set `$/` ("input record seperator") to `"|!|\n"` outside of the loop and `chomp` after each `readline`/`<STDIN>`. This moves more functionality into the C library (speed!) and avoids the creation of an anonymous array. Try benchmarking it.

Comment: Would that cause each read from STDIN to just give parts of the row one-by-one? So, for the example above, col1, col2, and col3|!| would be 3 separate reads from STDIN?

Comment: No, that would still give the whole row as one string, but without the final delimiter. I'm writing an answer with the complete example.

Comment: Thanks :) I'll try it out when you post.

Comment: First (new) rule of Optimization Club: We don't discuss optimization until we've used Devel::NYTProf to help us learn where our problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If written purely for efficiency, I'd write your code like this:

```
sub run_loop {
  local $/ = "|!|\n"; # set the record input terminator
                      # to the record seperator of our problem space
  while (<STDIN>) {       
    # remove the seperator
    chomp;

    # Split by field delimiter
    my @fields = split m/\|\^\|/, $_, -1;

    # Cycle through all column numbres in date_cols and convert date
    #  to yyyymmdd
    foreach $col (@date_cols) {
      if ($fields[$col] ne "") {
        # $fields[$col] = formatTime($fields[$col]);
        my $temp = $fields[$col];
        if (substr($temp, 4, 1) eq " ") {
          substr($temp, 4, 1) = "0";
        }       
        $fields[$col] = substr($temp, 7, 4).$months{substr($temp, 0, 3)}.substr($temp, 4, 2);
      }
    }
    print join("\022", @fields) . "\n";
  }
}
```

The optimizations are:

- Using `chomp` to remove the `|!|\n` string at the end
- Inlining the `formatTime` sub.

> Subroutine calls are extremely expensive in Perl. If subs have to be used very efficiently, prototype checking can be disabled with the `&subroutine(@args)` syntax. If `@args` are ommited, the current arguments `@_` are visible to the called sub. This can lead to bugs or additional performance. Use wisely. The `goto &subroutine;` syntax can be used as well, but this meddles with `return` (basically a tail call). Do not use.
>   
>   Further optimizations could include removing the hash lookup `%months`, as hashing is expensive.

Comment: I just ran this code with dummy input (2 fields per line) on 10M iterations. On my laptop, it finishes in 11s (with one date column), and in 8s when removing the foreach. This is actually quite okay, and wouldn't need optimization. IO *is* the limiting factor. @pilcros's solution takes a bit longer, with 18s. [citation needed]

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to benchmark on your data set to compare, but you can throw a regex at it.  (Made all the worse by your very regex-unfriendly field and record separators!)

```
my $i = 0;
our %months = map { $_ => sprintf('%02d', ++$i) } qw(Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec);

while (<DATA>) {
  s! \|\^\| !\022!xg;  # convert field separator
  s/ \| !\| $ //xg;        # strip record terminator
  s/\b(\w{3}) ( \d|\d\d) (\d{4}) \d\d:\d\d[AP]M\b/${3} . $months{$1} . sprintf('%02d', $2) /eg;
  print;
}
```

Won't do what you want if one of the non-`@date_cols` fields matches the date regex.

Comment: That is suprisingly elegant :) However, the `/x` modifier does not affect whitespace in the substitution string. You would include whitespaces around the output field seperator, i.e. `·\022·` where the dots are spaces. Also, wouldn't anchoring the second substitution at the end `$` improve efficiency?

Answer (score 0):

At my work sometimes i need to grep errorlogs etc from 350+ frontends. I use script template i calling "SMP grep" ;) Its simple:

1. `stat` file, get file length
2. Get "chunk length" = file_length / num_processors
3. Andjust chunk starts and ends so they start/end at "\n". Just `read()`, find "\n" and calculate offsets.
4. `fork()` to make num_processor workers, each working on own chunk

This can help if you use regexps in your grep or other CPU operations(as your case i think). Admins complaining this script eats disk throughput, but its only bottleneck here if server has 8 CPUs =) Also, obviously if you need to parse 1 week data you can divide between servers.

Tomorrow i can post the code if interested.